# Synchronizing multiple servers and local machines with the same data / source code

Tags: database, git, postgresql, docker, virtual-machine

**Background:**

*Building web app with a team of 2 developers.  RESTful backend via Flask.  Using Linux, Apache, Redis, and Postgres.*

- 3 servers:

  - 1 for production
  - 1 for development
  - 1 for UAT
- 4 databases:

  - 1 for PROD/UAT server
  - 1 for DEV server
  - 1 for developer A on his local machine
  - 1 for developer B on his local machine
- 2 local machines / developers

In addition to the 4 databases, the developers each have one additional database that serves testing.  This testing database needs to be the exact same at all times between the two developers.

Developer B has his own fork of the data, sending pull requests to the master repo, which is worked on by developer A.

**Problem:**

We have no real protocols to easily transfer data between each of the databases.  For example, the developers test databases are often different, which causes chaos.  Moving data from DEV to UAT/PROD is done manually.

Developers work in different environments and on different forks.  We use pull requests in github to transfer code to Developer A's main repo.

**Question**

What do you recommend as a solution to our database woes?  Is there a better way to share data?  Is there a better way for developer A and developer B to share their environment and source code?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this problem for an environment of similar size this year. The technology is different, but in short:

- 2-3 developers
- Each developer has a complete environment
- Integration, UAT and production server pairs (all VMs).
- Linux, Mongodb, Django and Angular

**Code**
After a few false starts we have settled on the feature branch approach and a good working proposition. See http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/. At the moment we have master for production and a development branch. Only one person works on a 'feature' (or we pair). Features should be short-lived. We might flip between multiple features when necessary. We can merge from one feature to another when we need to. It all comes out quite cleanly when we merge back into development. The overhead is minimal and we rarely step on each other's toes. When we do the diff makes it clear what we need to fix manually. A good GIT UI tool helps.

**Database**
You could use a shared database for development. We don't. Every developer has an independent environment. We may need collections, but usually from UAT or prod rather than each other. I have created a comprehensive admin page. On any environment we can export a collection set. There are mechanisms to send this export where needed. This is used to take prod data and place it in UAT for problem replication. We can then drop back to Integration and dev for repair. Similarly devs can share data using the same application admin page.

**Release**
Going up the chain from dev -> integration -> uat -> prod is also handled by the application admin page. Any system can export, but only up to the next stage. It is not automatically imported. The import is not automagic. The admin on the target environment is told that a release is available. They can import it from the admin page. We do the same for code and database collections.

It is useful to have it integrated rather than knowing which script to run. It could be a separate application if that worked batter in your environment.